# Analytics Pattern (Get view per day)

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

I have a trouble about schema pattern for my project.

I would like to count the view per day for each pages and calculate rank.

I'm working with node.js and MySQL(Store pages)/MongoDB(Store every view with visitors infos)

Is that more efficient, performant to update my table (MySQL) everyday with a cron at midnight (w/ view per day row 0) then query this page or to query an aggregate in mongoDB to get the view of this day (I have the timestamp).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, MongoDB is not suitable for your case.
It would be better, faster and cheaper to use cache service, where you can increment counter for page.
Take a look at [redis](https://redis.io/). You can implement behaviour like [this](https://gist.github.com/fbrnc/19c3ce69bbc5b4083b5a3653109f2148).

So, the main goal to remove mongo, if it used only for counter.

According to your question about performance, it is super fast to request values stored in redis, because complexity is O(1).

Comment: Thanks. But i'm using MongoDB to store analytics data (Like each view, click on some parts of my pages and user-information like (mobile devices, what kind of navigator) is that a wrong use of MongoDB and i would like to display in my back-office charts. 

Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Webalex depends on your goals. But redis is really good for metrics. As for me, things like each view, click and user-information like (mobile devices, what kind of navigator) could be easily stored in redis. Redis allows you to store data on disk, which means it can work as persistent storage. And you can create records there with TTL (time to live), which means no need for manual database clear. So, just play around with it, read a few manuals and decide for yourself